# Read file character by character starting at a particular line

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am using `tkinter` to bring up a dialog box where the user can choose a file. I want to parse that file starting on line 11. The file looks like this:

```
(115,147)
(6,145)
(44,112)
(17,72)
(112,1)
(60,142)
(47,158)
(35,43)
(34,20)
(38,33)
11101111110111011111111110111111111111111111111011111111111111110111111111
111101111101111a11011122112011222222211112111221221111101111111111110111ab
..more down here
```

How do I retrieve each character when they are not separated by spaces? I know I have to start off like this:

```
# Bring up save dialog box
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])

# Check if user clicked cancel
if file is None or file is '':
    return False

# Read from file
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    # Do something here with f.read()
```

I want to get these numbers in a list (each at their own index):

```
11101111110111011111111110111111111111111111111011111111111111110111111111
111101111101111a11011122112011222222211112111221221111101111111111110111ab
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please make your question more clear. You have a comment "Write to file" when you are reading from it.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Dont be sorry. Just improve it. Still not clear what is the final output/result you are looking for. Should all the lines be stored as a list of lists after 10th line with each character in line as a separate character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to `read()` data from the file, and then split by newlines to get a list of lines in the file:

```
lines=f.read().split("\n")
```

If you only need from line 11 to the end, you can use:

```
lines=lines[10:]
```

And then iterate through it, using `list()` to split into characters:

```
characters=[list(line)for line in lines]
```

Output:

```
[['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'a', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# consume 10 lines
for _ in range(10):
    f.readline()

# read one character at a time
# f.read(1) will return '' when you reach eof
c = f.read(1)
while c:
    # do something with c
    c = f.read(1)
```

For that matter, since lists and strings are sort of the same in python, you could just say

```
# consume 10 lines
for _ in range(10):
    f.readline()

rest = f.read()
```

and then rest would be a list/string with everything in it...i.e., `rest[0]` is the first char, `rest[1]` the next, etc. Be aware that you will capture newlines too this way.